# Error importing a cffi python module from AWS Lambda Layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am having a problem importing the `argon2-cffi` [python module (version 20.1.0)](https://argon2-cffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) from an AWS Lambda Layer into an AWS Lambda function.

This seems to apply to all packages that have C as a base, because I tested this with `pandas` and got the same results.

My cloudformation config for the Layer is the following:

```
  MyLib:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: my-lib
      Description: In-house and 3rd party dependencies for my app.
      ContentUri: lambdas/lib/.
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.8
```

and the folder structure inside `/lib` is this:

```
lib
├── python
│   ├── app
│   │   └── ...
│   └── lib/python3.8/site-packages
│       ├── argon2
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── argon2_cffi-20.1.0.dist-info
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── ...
│       └── stdnum
│           └── ...
└── requirements.txt
```

as per [recommendations from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path), where the folder `python/app` contains my custom library and the folder `python/lib/python3.8/site-packages` contains 3rd party packages.

I know that since argon2 depends on C-code, [it must be installed on the runtime environment that the Lambda function using it will be hosted in](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/), so I use a docker image provided by AWS to install the packages into `lib/python3.8/site-packages` using the command

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

The lambda function I'm trying to run is configured in the cloudformation template as

```
  AuthorizerFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambdas/handlers
      Handler: authorizer.handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      ...
      Layers:
        - !Ref MyLib
```

and starts with these imports:

```
# authorizer.py

import app.utils as utils
import stdnum
from argon2 import PasswordHasher
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'authorizer': No module named 'argon2._ffi'
```

meaning that `app` and `stdnum` both get imported successfully, but not `argon2`.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

I would also welcome any suggestions on another hashing library with a tried and tested hashing algorithm.

UPDATE: Updating my `cffi`, `pip` and `setuptools` as is recommended [here](https://argon2-cffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) did not do the trick.

UPDATE 2: I can see that the argon being installed using the docker command is the linux compatible one, since the output includes these lines:

```
Collecting argon2-cffi==20.1.0
  Downloading argon2_cffi-20.1.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (97 kB)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so the answer to my problem is a bit of an awkward one. I'll post it here anyhow in case it might depthen an understanding for someone.

I am using git for source control and used a template from VS Code for the `.gitignore` file. Furthermore, I have set up an automatic build and deployment process, which builds the Lambda application based on the content in the git repo.

After days of trying to debug this problem I found out that `.so` files were missing from the  `argon2_cffi` folder in the Lambda layer. The culprit was the aforementioned `.gitignore` file, which contained these lines:

```
# C extensions
*.so
```

No wonder none of the C-based python packages were working!

I removed said lines from `.gitignore` and committed all the `.so` files to the repo that had never made it to the Lambda Layer before, and now everything is working fine.